# Facebook with actionscript 3 on Flashdevelop : JSON Conventions Issue

Tags: json, facebook, actionscript-3, flashdevelop

I'm trying to use Facebook with Actionscript 3 on Flashdevelop, i've been following this tutorial about setting Facebook :

http://supertommy.me/content/2012/getting-started-open-graph-as3/

The code seems to be clean but i get this error :

```
WARNING: For content targeting Flash Player version 14 or higher, ExternalInterface escapes strings using JSON conventions. To maintain compatibility, content published to earlier Flash Player versions continues to use the legacy escaping behavior.
```

I checked the flash player target on my Flashdevelop in the project properties, in tab Output the flash player was set to 10.1, am i missing something ?

Answer (score 0):

Use the clause at the end:

> content published to earlier Flash Player versions continues to use the legacy escaping behavior.

as a warning that newer players may render the JSON string differently than the one in FlashDevelop, so you may need to test using a newer debug player as well to avoid security issues.

**References**

- [Adobe Security Bulletin: APSB13-08](http://www.adobe.com/support/security/bulletins/apsb13-08.html)
- [V-100: Adobe Flash Player Bugs Let Remote Users Execute Arbitrary Code](http://energy.gov/cio/articles/v-100-adobe-flash-player-bugs-let-remote-users-execute-arbitrary-code)